# postDelayed OnClickListener is not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, timedelay, postdelayed

I am trying to implement a delay on button click, each second I need to remove one item from a list called `solved_cells`, the list initially has 16 items. below is what I did:

```
solve_all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                   while (solved_cells.size()>=1) {
                       v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               //Execute code here
                        solved_cells.remove(solved_cells.size() - 1);
                          }
                       }, 1000L);

                    }
        }
    });
```

but each time I debug , I see the code reach to :

```
v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

and doesn't touch the `public void run() {` function, Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: `postDelayed` just puts the `Runnable` into the queue for later execution, it does not run it immediately. This turns your `while` into an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know exactly what your problem in your code but you can use timer instead like this by creating TimerTask class

```
   Timer timer;
   MyTimerTask timerTask;
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (solved_cells.size() > 0) {
                        solved_cells.remove(solved_cells.size() - 1);
                    } else {

                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and in your listener you can declare it like this

```
solve_all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
      Timer t = new Timer();
      t.schedule(timerTask , 1000L);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same problem. your code removes only one item from the list. when implementing while loop like this 'public void onClick(View v) {while (solved_cells.size() >= 1) {
      timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
      Timer t = new Timer();
      t.schedule(timerTask , 1000L);

    }}' then the 'run()' function is not called.

Comment: I need to remove all items, one by one each second.

Comment: Thanks Mosa, I edited your answer to call the timer and it's working now.  ' Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (Game.solved_cells.size() > 0) {
                            int yyy = cells.get(solved_cells.get(solved_cells.size() - 1));
                            Game.solved_cells.remove(Game.solved_cells.size() - 1);
                            timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
                            Timer t = new Timer();
                            t.schedule(timerTask , 1000L);'

Comment: this must remove one item each second until there is no items

Comment: ok am glad this solution work for you, if it worked fine pleaswe accept the answer and vote up